# Transferring files via Python's ftplib nondeterministically times out

Tags: python, ftp, timeout, ftplib

I'm trying to use ftplib to transfer a set of files from my computer (running 64-bit Windows 7) to a Linux server. The process is similar to this snippet of test code (server address, username, and password changed, obviously):

```
import ftplib
import os.path
import os

host     = "some.ftp.server.com"
username = "username"
password = "password"

outDir = "/some/output/directory"

def transfer_files():
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(host, username, password)

    ftp.cwd(outDir)
    names = ftp.nlst()
    if "transferred" not in names:
        ftp.mkd("transferred")
    ftp.cwd("transferred")
    names = ftp.nlst()

    # Transfrer arbitrary files to the server
    filesToTransfer = os.listdir('.')
    for fName in filesToTransfer:
        if not os.path.isfile(fName):
            continue
        if fName in names:
            ftp.delete(fName)
        with open(fName, 'r') as f:
            ftp.storbinary("STOR %s" % fName, f)
        print fName

    ftp.quit()

    print "Done"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    transfer_files()
```

The behavior I'm seeing is that most files transfer quickly and successfully, but randomly a file will instead time out and raise the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 37, in <module>
    transfer_files()
  File "Test.py", line 29, in transfer_files
    ftp.storbinary("STOR %s" % base, f)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\ftplib.py", line 471, in storbinary
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\ftplib.py", line 376, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\ftplib.py", line 335, in ntransfercmd
    conn = socket.create_connection((host, port), self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

The file that times out is different each time I run the program, but it always seems to happen to one file or another. Why could the transfer be randomly timing out, and what can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with network requests in bulk, it's completely normal to get a certain number of timeouts - it's even expected. Rather than try to prevent timeouts from happening (because they always will), you should add logic to your application to handle cases where timeouts occur. Since you're uploading files in bulk, that probably looks like re-attempting the upload when that exception gets raised.

Comment: Changing the timeout time to 1 second and retrying transfers until they succeed seems to work. What is going on behind the scenes when transfers "randomly" time out?

Comment: Every network request gets broken down into a series of packets that are transmitted across the wire (or WiFi, or fiber-optic cable). A timeout happens when your computer doesn't receive acknowledgement from the computer at the other end that it got those packets, either because some of them got lost on the way there, or because its acknowledgement was lost on the way back.

For most purposes, computer programs behave "ideally" but data transmission brings with it all the imperfections of the physical world that can prevent proper data transfer.